# Data types in java CQL driver

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cql3, cassandra-2.0

Is there a way to use short and byte values in CQL? I've defined a table with int fields and can store and read short and byte values from there, but if I try to bind a value in a prepared statement, I get an error. I also tried varint, but still no luck. That's the exception I get:

```
Invalid type for value 1 of CQL type varint, expecting class java.math.BigInteger but class java.lang.Byte provided
```

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "Timeline" (
    "BucketID" varchar,
    "CreationTime" timestamp,
    "Attr01" varint,
    "Attr02" bigint,
    "Attr03" varint,
    "Attr04" varint,
    "Attr05" uuid,
    "Message" text,
    PRIMARY KEY (("BucketID", "Attr01"), "CreationTime", "Attr02", "Attr03", "Attr04", "Attr05")
) WITH COMPACT STORAGE AND CLUSTERING ORDER BY ("CreationTime" DESC);
```

Is there a way to use shorts/bytes, instead of always casting/creating integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a link to the [CQL3 data types to Java types](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/#cql-to-java-type-mapping) chart.

> I also tried varint, but still no luck.

I would have thought that `varint` should have worked, too.  But I can see (in the link referenced above) that `varint` maps to `BigInteger`, so no luck there.  In any case, it would appear that a mapping between a `short` and a CQL3 integer-based type does not exist.

However, if you want to store bytes you can use the `blob` CQL3 type.

**EDIT 20180727**

It looks like `smallint` in CQL now maps to `java.lang.Short`.

Comment: @aroth link fixed.